# Vagrant Box Error: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 Protocol mismatch

Tags: vagrant

In setting up a vagrant box I got this error. I followed the directions but do not know what to do next.

Comment: Are you trying to connect through a port other than 22? If not, is port 22 blocked by your firewall?

Comment: can you share your Vagrantfile and also indicates if you get the error at `vagrant up` (can you boot the machine, if so can you access with virtual box or vmware depending which one you are using ?) or `vagrant ssh`